# Can I migrate preference data for Mobile Push?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilestudio

Is it possible to migrate push consent (opted in/out) from an external system into Mobile Push? As this maybe go down to device level how would this be imported/stored in Marketing Cloud